# Change the background color to transparent

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to make my (page)background on  the website transparent, so the text and content scroll over the fixed background image. I know i need to do this in css. I have tried all kind of possibilities, to set the background color; #EFFFFF, "transparent", initial color etc, but noting worked sofar, it is still white. Any tips or directions to follow? (i build my site on weebly btw)

Comment: You want to make the body background transparent??? Make a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: You do not want the background to be transparent, you just want a background.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this what is a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net. Also, you can click snippet button in the post editor to insert a snippet in your post.

Comment: DIV element background is `transparent` by Default, which makes your question even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, transparent color is any color with `alpha=0`. So you can use:

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)
```

where only the last `0` which sets alpha matters.

Also

```
background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0);
```

Again, only the last zero representing alpha matters.

Comment: `background-color:#FFFFFF00` Android might be.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best - most cross browser way to have a transparent white background is to make a small white image like 2px x 2px and set the opacity on that and save it as a `.png` then simply include it in your css:

```
element {
    background-image: url('mytransparentimage.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: We've moved far from IE6 those days... Also why `background-repeat: repeat;` it's repeated in all browsers AFAIK by default.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment I don't think you want a transparent background, but rather just a background on your `<body>` tag. You can use the CSS `background-image` with `background-attachment:fixed`.  There's a runnable code example below:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/10/);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id euismod leo. Suspendisse potenti. Proin elementum sodales ligula, in aliquet massa accumsan a. Donec molestie pharetra risus, vel congue sapien ornare at. Nulla mi nulla, iaculis ut est eget, pretium efficitur mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut vel justo et dui lobortis iaculis sit amet non nisi.

Fusce felis eros, tempor eget pulvinar sit amet, tristique a elit. Etiam accumsan sagittis risus vel laoreet. Maecenas nulla odio, ultricies non ipsum sed, vehicula sodales nisl. Nunc vitae dignissim mauris. Maecenas venenatis turpis quis arcu malesuada pellentesque. Donec ut purus eu ante ornare aliquam. Mauris at blandit enim, at sagittis purus. Integer sollicitudin lorem et interdum dignissim. Etiam eget commodo eros. Nam lacinia ante in vehicula eleifend. Morbi dignissim est nisi, suscipit consectetur arcu auctor quis.

Duis eu elit pellentesque, varius turpis ac, malesuada tellus. Praesent consectetur velit vitae risus finibus dictum. Morbi at dui non mi elementum pretium. Donec id posuere felis. Maecenas laoreet blandit nisl vel commodo. Cras mattis mi non velit scelerisque faucibus. Cras non felis in tellus dignissim accumsan.

Donec condimentum non augue non tempus. Donec diam risus, imperdiet eu vulputate ut, consequat quis tortor. In scelerisque dignissim nunc. Praesent quis fringilla metus. Vivamus sit amet pharetra libero. Etiam porta malesuada enim in fringilla. Aenean sed dui in velit rutrum ornare quis vitae velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam semper congue luctus. Etiam faucibus ornare ligula, sit amet interdum nulla. Ut rutrum odio non arcu pharetra fringilla. Morbi est mi, molestie pharetra suscipit nec, elementum ac nisl. Sed nisi dui, porta eget elementum sit amet, placerat vel purus. Ut hendrerit tellus id urna maximus, eget euismod massa tincidunt. In venenatis sapien sed est iaculis sagittis.

Ut enim mi, suscipit non ligula condimentum, mattis semper leo. Integer egestas eleifend scelerisque. Suspendisse tempus tempor nunc, vitae varius metus luctus vitae. Mauris vel ante nec erat tristique convallis nec id mi. Mauris lacinia lobortis risus sed pulvinar. Fusce faucibus tellus vestibulum, varius orci quis, tincidunt massa. Donec consequat urna id quam gravida tincidunt. Sed turpis massa, sagittis non consequat vel, sagittis nec magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas in tortor lorem. Praesent id ante vitae magna sollicitudin vulputate.
```